# Access input value in ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to get input field's value inside a click handler inside ReactDOM.render().

The code inside App.js is

```
<input ref={node => {
            this.todoInput = node
        }} className="pull-left" />
        <button onClick={this.props.addTodo}>Add Todo</button>
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<App
    todos={store.getState().todos}
    addTodo={() => {
        console.log(this.refs);

        //store.dispatch({
        //     type: 'ADD_TODO',
         //  id: nextTodoId++,
          {/*text: this.refs.todoInput.value*/}
        {/*});*/}

        {/*this.refs.todoInput.value = '';*/}
    }}
  />,
  document.getElementById('root'));
```

Inside addTodo function , how can I access my refs object? Or ultimately to get todoInput's value

**Update** - One of the answers provided below works for me as an alternative solution. However, the reason what is bugging me is simple. I render App component inside of the ReactDOM.render(). Shouldn't App directly have access to it's input field as it is through some mechanism ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you refer the `todo` inside `addTodo` function like `this.refs.todoInput`. Here `this` refers to the current instance where you are rendering `ReactDOM.render`. 
So  your `input` which is inside the `app` instance cannot be accessed in a different instance.

If you wanna access it your way then you need to add a ref to your app like this

```
ReactDOM.render(<App
 ref={appInstance => { this.appInstance = appInstance;} }
 todos={store.getState().todos}
 .....
```

Now you can access the input inside app instance like below

```
addTodo={() => {
  // your value from todoInput will be here..
  const value = this.appInstance.todoInput.value;
}}
```

Comment: Refreshing! Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to make `App` a stateful component and then you could pass on the `ref` or the value of the `ref` to the `this.props.addTodo` function.

Example code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick() {
    this.props.addTodo(this.todoInput.value);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <input ref={node => { this.todoInput = node }} className="pull-left" />
      <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Add Todo</button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Alright! I do have a stateful component for App.js. Also, I did read many answers prior to posting which make use of handleClick() as a function inside App component. So, my basic question remains, is there no way to access directly in ReactDOM.render() the input's value?

Comment: You could pass down a function, which would bind the node to the parent component if that is what you want to do.

Comment: Appreciated and upvoted. I got my reason by @Panther. However, I do understand that practically I would be doing this solution. Was just looking for reasoning.Cheers!